# Gitlab - Não consigo mais clonar nem fazer pull do meu repositório

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Tenho o Gitlab em meu servidor Ubuntu em produção há 8 meses. Não consigo clonar nem fazer pull de um repositório (+/- 400mb), porém, outros repositórios menores funcionam normalmente.

Não sei nem por onde começar para descobrir o problema.

Obs: Estou usando pelo TortoiseGit. Quando peço um pull, aparece o status:

```
git.exe pull -v --no-rebase --progress  "origin"

POST git-upload-pack (gzip 1057 to 604 bytes)
POST git-upload-pack (gzip 1157 to 653 bytes)
```

Não sai disso.

Comment: tenta fazer um novo clone com depth usa git clone --depth=1 URL

Comment: Com esta opção funcionou! O que ela faz exatamente?

Comment: Essa opção não puxa todo histórico do repositório, faz um clone raso em uma profundidade especifica. Na documentação: Create a 'shallow' clone with a history truncated to the
 specified number of revisions.

Comment: Entendi. Mas porque o meu diretório (que já existe e trabalho nele diariamente) parou de fazer o Pull?

Comment: Não sei. Tenta verificar se você esta no branch correto la, se não esta detached, se o branch existe no origin. Se tiver tudo certo deixe rodando enquanto não der erro

Comment: Está tudo certinho. Inclusive o último Pull/Push foi na semana passada. Ontem deixei por cerca de 2 horas e nada.